# How many unique strings is possible with set amount of characters and length?

Tags: math

If I have two characters (`a, b`) and a length of three (`aaa, aab ...`), how do I count how many unique strings I can make of that (and what is the math method called)?

Is this correct?

```
val = 1, amountCharacters = 2, length = 3;
for (i = 1; i <= length; ++i) { val = amountCharacters*val; uniqueStrings = val }
```

This example returns 8 which is correct. If I try with something higher, like `amountCharacters = 10` it returns 1000. Is it still correct?

Comment: Let me get this straight. You are asking how many unique strings with length L can one construct using only N character, right?

Comment: How is 8 correct here? Shouldn't __unique__ strings be `aab, aba, baa`, i.e. 3?

Comment: @HarshGupta; aaa, aab, aba, abb, baa, bab, bba, bbb.

Comment: @SimonSvensson, thanks. The worst part of my comment was, I took the liberty of including `a` twice but didn't even notice `b`. Poor me & `b`.

Comment: Please refer [permutations](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-given-length/) [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-permutations-with-repetition-of-characters/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have n different characters and the length is k, there are exactlty n<sup>k</sup> possible strings you can form. Each character independently of the rest can be one of n different options and there are k total choices to make. Your code is correct.

For 2 possible characters and 10 letters, there are exactly 1024 possible strings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I couldn't run `n^k` in Chrome's developer tools, that's why I wrote this. I found `Math.pow(n, k)` for javascript and `pow($n, $k)` for PHP when I googled a bit more. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The same rules than [Base](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28mathematics%29) mathematics concept applies.

So the short answer is `amountCharacters ^ length`.

Longest natural answer.

- The first letter will have X possible values
- The second letter will have X*X possible values
- and so on ..
- X equals the number of possible values, i-e the amount of characters in your question

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, if you have N characters and want to construct a string of length L, the number of combinations is just N^L (e.g. N to the power of L).

There are various other results you can get if there are different limitations on what the string can contain, e.g. combinations or permutations.