# Built jQuery extension, but not allowing max return values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random, extend

I put together a jsfiddle of the problem here:  https://jsfiddle.net/sd1x3am3/5/

Basically, I built an extension called `$.generateSerial` which takes 3 parameters.  The first parameter is a formula, the 2nd is the characters allowed, and the 3rd is the serials to not include in the return value.  Basically, the extension allows you to generate a unique, random serial that is none of the serials in the 3rd parameter, and none of the serials that are returned within the `output` variable each time `$.generateSerial` gets called within the `for` loop.

For some reason, `$.generateSerial` returns `""` within the loop when `i = 146`, but there should be more values for it to return, so it should not return `""`.

The formula is `XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX` and the chars allowed are:  `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789`, which means any of these chars can replace any of the `X` chars in the `formula`.  But there should be more than 145/146 results returned, not counting what is within the `currSerials` array.  There should be way more serials that can be generated.

But I can't figure out why it is not generating all of the possible serials and stopping...

```
$.extend({
    generateSerial: function(formula, chrs, checks) {
        var formula = formula && formula != "" ? formula : 'XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX', // Default Formula to use, should change to what's most commonly used!
            chrs = chrs && chrs != "" ? chrs : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", // Default characters to randomize, if not defined!
            len = (formula.match(/X/ig) || []).length,
            oStatic = formula.match(/[^X]+/ig) || [],
            indices = [],
            lenChecks = checks.length || 0,
            rand;

        // Let's first find out if it's possible to create another random serial from params
        // Should put the formula below through a stress test here to be sure it works!
        var possible = (len * chrs.length) - lenChecks;

        // return empty string if not possible!
        if (possible <= 0)
            return '';

        var currIndex = 0;

        // Getting all indices here of all strings that are not X or x
        for (var o = 0; o < oStatic.length; o++) {
            currIndex = formula.indexOf(oStatic[o], currIndex);
            indices.push(currIndex);
            currIndex = currIndex + oStatic[o].length; // set the position to start at for next loop! incrementing...
        }

        do {
            rand = Array(len).join().split(',').map(function() {
                return chrs.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chrs.length));
            }).join('');

            // Rebuild with indices, if exists!
            if (indices && indices.length > 0) {
                for (var x = 0; x < indices.length; x++)
                    rand = rand.insert(indices[x], oStatic[x]);
            }
        } while (checks && $.inArray(rand, checks) !== -1);

        return rand;
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me with this please?  Could something be wrong with my `possible` variable within the extension?  Is it not correct?

Even tried it without the `currSerials` array, with it initially empty and only generates 576 serials before it says it can not generate anymore.  You can see it here:  https://jsfiddle.net/sd1x3am3/8/

```
var currSerials = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
    var output = $.generateSerial('XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', currSerials);

    $(".serials").append($("<p />").text((i+1) + '. ' + output));
    if (output != "")
        currSerials.push(output);
    else
    {
        alert('Can not generate anymore serials, stopped at ' + i + '.');
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I remove the possible check, it seems to work, but honestly, I need to know if it is possible to create another unique random serial number with the formula and chars and checks array given before starting the `do...while...` loop.  How come `possible` is not returning the correct amount of possible serial numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussions, I find that you are not after permutations, so you should be using the following to find the [total possible items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19536837),

```
var possible=Math.pow(chrs.length,len) - lenChecks
```

Comment: Ok, so why does this not alert me of anything:  https://jsfiddle.net/sd1x3am3/9/  I should get alert here that it is not possible to generate anymore serials, but I get nothing.  Actually I get error:  `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: When permuting, total number of characters should be greater than placeholders, else you will run into negative numbers for `chrs.length-len` and factorial will run into infinite loop.

Comment: I am using `$.generateSerial('XX-XX', 'AB', currSerials);` it should know that after it depletes all possible serial combinations, it should return `''`, but it does not.

Comment: So, there is no way to account for when formula length is less than total number of characters?  Can't have infinite loop here.

Comment: change `x==0` to `x<=0` in factorial and `possible` now gives you the total global possible items`. subtract it from generated items count to know if it can generate new.

Comment: generated items count?  You mean the checks array?  `lenChecks`?

Comment: `var possible=Math.round(factorial(chrs.length)/factorial(chrs.length-len)) - lenChecks;` Updated the answer. substract lenChecks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108735/discussion-between-solomon-closson-and-mathew).

Comment: I substract lenChecks, but it causes more problems, see here:  https://jsfiddle.net/sd1x3am3/10/ I invited you to chat to try to discuss this more.

Comment: If you want we can collaborate on this via jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/sd1x3am3/10/#&togetherjs=G69zSLPteB

Comment: Thanks for your help Mathew, that nailed it!